# Vite.js + React: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, vite

I'm migrating a large application created with CRA to Vite.js

I followed [this guide](https://darekkay.com/blog/create-react-app-to-vite/) to configure the new bundler with the existing app and now everything seems fine when running the development server.

However, when trying to compile the production build, I run in the following error:

```sh
vite v2.6.14 building for production...
✓ 162 modules transformed.
[vite:react-jsx] unknown: Maximum call stack size exceeded
file: /Users/matteocarpi/Documents/Web/philip-morris/aws-amplify-multi-tenant/node_modules/react-i18next/dist/es/Trans.js
error during build:
RangeError: unknown: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at getJSXProps (/Users/matteocarpi/Documents/Web/aws-amplify-multi-tenant/node_modules/vite-react-jsx/dist/cjs/babelRestoreJsx.js:79:29)
    at getJSXNode (/Users/matteocarpi/Documents/Web/aws-amplify-multi-tenant/node_modules/vite-react-jsx/dist/cjs/babelRestoreJsx.js:31:23)
    at PluginPass.CallExpression (/Users/matteocarpi/Documents/Web/aws-amplify-multi-tenant/node_modules/vite-react-jsx/dist/cjs/babelRestoreJsx.js:165:30)
    at newFn (/Users/matteocarpi/Documents/Web/aws-amplify-multi-tenant/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:177:21)
    at NodePath._call (/Users/matteocarpi/Documents/Web/aws-amplify-multi-tenant/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:53:20)
    at NodePath.call (/Users/matteocarpi/Documents/Web/aws-amplify-multi-tenant/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:40:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/matteocarpi/Documents/Web/aws-amplify-multi-tenant/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:100:31)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/matteocarpi/Documents/Web/aws-amplify-multi-tenant/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:103:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/matteocarpi/Documents/Web/aws-amplify-multi-tenant/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:109:21)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/matteocarpi/Documents/Web/aws-amplify-multi-tenant/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:109:21)
```

I understand it's something to do with Babel and i18next, but I'm a bit stuck in what the specific problem is.

Any tips on how to debug further?

Thanks in advance,

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using the reactJsx plugin only in development:

vite.config.js:

```js
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const isDevEnv = mode === 'development';
  
  return {
    plugins: [
       isDevEnv && react(),
    ]
  }
}
```

as suggested in [this issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/5082#issuecomment-944231660)

Answer (score 5):

##### .env known issue

For those still facing the problem, there's a known issue with the [motdotla/dotenv-expand](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv-expand/issues/98) package (used by Vite) related to duplicated variables' names in the `.env` file.

> Issue opened for vite: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/13399

The error happens when a variable references another variable with the same name, so check your `.env` file for duplicated names.

This works:

```
// .env

APP_NAME=$NAME
```

This breaks:

```
// .env

APP_NAME=$APP_NAME

or

APP_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Comment: You saved me from endless frustration, it's insane that this still hasn't been fixed